# Apply Context/Conditions to a Views result item?

Tags: 9

If you are using Context for a node, the node itself typically comes from the node page you are on. In some cases, you may want to apply the same context to views results on a node as well - but they are getting the same argument instead of the node of the result. How can you supply the result item as the context argument to conditions?